# How to open .xml files in Cryengine 5.6.2?

Tags: cryengine

I am new at this engine and I am trying to understad its stuff before developing a game(I have good prior experience with unity and UE4) and this got me lots of headaches trying to understand it. My main problem is opening a `.xml` file, first of all I created a new project using ***third person shooter*** template and I started to study C# code and how character was animated using `.xml` files.

I know that cryengine V uses a thing called flow graph that makes the logic of an object by displaying a graph reading xml text.

What I have tried:

1. Clicking 1000 billion times the .xml file.
   [image]
2. Trying to open it by importing into the flow chart thing.
   [image]

How do I open this .xml file in a flow graph? There is poor documentation about this in docs.cryengine and makes hard for us to understand the logic.

Comment: How did you create this particular xml file, and what markup does it contain? What do you hope to do with it?

Comment: when you open flow graph(similar to blueprints in UE4) you can create nodes in a graphical interface and when you save them they save as .xml and you can open them again as flow graph with no problems, but in this case the file I am trying to open is generated by template. Remember if you want a different animation/logic you should be able to edit that generated xml file in a graphical interface, I dont want to edit it by code because I do not know xml.